# Swift 4. Blank area below

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, storyboard

Не могу понять откуда взялась эта пустая область внизу и как ее убрать. В Storyboard ее на страницах нигде нет и при скроллинге мелькает серая полоса.
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

[image: blank area]

[image: layers]

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это у Вас ячейка и, соответственно, при нажатии на нее срабатывает didSelect, который показывается серым цветом. Можно убрать select и сделать распознание тапа, или поменять цвет селекта.

Comment: а как убрать эту ячейку? т.к это белое пространство лишнее и я не понял как оно образовалось. у меня в слоях UIView - NavController - ViewController(на котором находятся эти все элементы которые на экране)

Comment: А, нет, я не прав, у Вас обычная шторка между экранами. Просто второй VC  у Вас почему-то не на весь экран, поэтому получается такой переход. Смотрите настройки размеров второго VC.

Comment: Я смотрел настройки VC и он не должен быть такого размера.

Comment: Без кода непонятно, к сожалению.